# TabBar setting setting state of tabviews

Tags: flutter, tabbar, tabview

I have a Main page with a tabbar with 5 tabs. In Main page, i load a JSON from internet and set different parts of it in each tab. It's a world cup app, showing a tab for each match fase (groups, round of 16, quarterfinals, semifinal, and final). When each tab is loaded, i get the json and build a list view.

In additional, i want to set a button to reload the information (something like a fab or action in appbar). But, when i reload the JSON, how do i setstate of the actual tab?

This is my Main page widget build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    leading: new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    ),
    title: new Text(title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: <Widget>[
        new GroupStageMatches(),
        new RoundOfSixteen(),
        new QuarterFinals(),
        new SemiFinal(),
        new Final(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: new TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: <Widget>[
        new Tab(text: "Grupos"),
        new Tab(text: "Oitavas"),
        new Tab(text: "Quartas"),
        new Tab(text: "Semi"),
        new Tab(text:"Final"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        sing.updateData();
      });
    }
  ),
);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple solution would be to create valueNotifier in your singleton

```
  ValueNotifier<String> valueNotifier = new ValueNotifier<String>("");
```

Then, inside each tab in `initState` do

```
sing.valueNotifier.addListener(_valueChanged)
```

and on `dispose` clean up listeners.

to notify listeners, you would change the value. If the value is different thatn the previous one it will notify the listeners. This will call `_valueChanged` method

```
sing.valueNotifier.value = "HelloWorld";
```

Once `_valueChanged` gets called, you can set state in your tab.

EDIT: based on code example

You see, value notifier holds the value that you will need in your class. so once the getJSON resolves, listener will be called in your view.

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = new Singleton._internal();
  ValueNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> groupsJson =
      new ValueNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>>(null);
  ValueNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> eliminationJson =
      new ValueNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>>(null);

  factory Singleton() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Singleton._internal() {
    // updateData();
  }


  updateGroupsJson() async {
    _groupsJson.value = await this.getJson(
        "http://www.srgoool.com.br/call?ajax=get_classificacao2&id_fase=1796");
  }

  updateEliminationJson() async {
    _eliminationJson.value = await this.getJson(
        "http://www.srgoool.com.br/call?ajax=get_chaves&id_ano_campeonato=434");
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getJson(url) async {
    print("loading");
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("loaded");
      var teste = json.decode(response.body);
      return teste;
    } else {
      print("erro");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

In your view:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  sing = new Singleton();
  sing.groupsJson.addListener(onGroupJson);
  sing.updateGroupsJson();

  //you can already draw your frontend with latest groupsJson. Thiss will just update the view when you get a new one
}

void onGroupJson{
  setState ((){
    // assing fields that you need for drawing the view 
  });
}
```

Comment: But I want to setState of the current tab. In Tab i have a boolean variable called isLoading, which when it's true it shows a CricleProgress and when the data is loaded i want to set it false.

Comment: btw, my method updateData() doesnt return anything, it just update the data in mey Singleton (sing is the instance of it).

Comment: It should propagate down the tree and change states where it needs redraw. Check this presentation if you want to make it more decoupled. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI

Comment: Ok, I thought it was calling some async server. Definitely check the presentation I linked, it should shed some light on some cool ideas, to big to write in this small answer.

Comment: why  3 ValueNotifier?

Comment: just an example, that you can initialize it with value

Comment: If you just want to notify listeners, without holding value you can use ChangeNotifier

Comment: If you will have a lot of listeners to the same value, you can use streams or even rxDart library like in the presentation

Comment: So, let me check if i understand it. 
ValueNotifier<String> valueNotifier = new ValueNotifier<int>(""); => this is my first value of the variable.|||||

sing.valueNotifier.addListener(_valueChanged) => here i'm setting a callback function which will be executed when the variable have the values changed|||||||

sing.valueNotifier.value = "HelloWorld"; => here i'm changing the value of the variable, executing the method i passed.|||||||

So, i set it on my initState tab and each time i reload json (the variable value) the function i passed will be executed?

Comment: Yes correct. Value Notifier holds one value of type <T> . I edited my answer because  `new ValueNotifier<String>("");` needs to be string. You can implement ChangeNotifier in your singleton if you want to manualy dispatch changes. You can also check the presentation for more advance usage

Comment: hey! the ValueNotifier worked but i'm still getting an error. It's weird! First of all, i'm getting the JSON and building de ListView, OK! I set a fab to reload the json, but when i reload i get "Class 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>' has no instance method '[]'.". That's weird because i'm reading the same way as before.. it should work fine

Comment: but it works first time, just don't work to the next.. i'm calling the same method!
here is the code if want to see, it's in views/matches/matches-group-stage.dart and utils/singleton.dart 
https://github.com/joaovirgili/flutter_bolao_da_copa

Comment: Here is little simpler example